# Converting dataframe column of mixed types to int, ignore values with non numeric characters

Tags: python, pandas

df:

```
    IDs
0  text
1   001
2     1

df = pd.DataFrame({'IDs': ['text', '001', '1']})
```

And I'd like to convert the values to int where possible so strings corresponding to the same entity, `001` and `1`, become identical values, through dropping the '00' prefix.

[This is demonstrated in pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html), but neither `df['IDs'] = pd.to_numeric(df['IDs'], errors='ignore')` or `df['IDs'] = df['IDs'].astype(int, errors='ignore')` is changing anything.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is expected, docs [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) say:

> If ‘ignore’, then invalid parsing will return the input.

so it means if invalid at least one value it return same values.

Possible solution is use custom function with `try-except`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'IDs': ['text', '001', '1']})
def func(x):
    try:
        return int(x)
    except:
        return x

df['IDs'] = df['IDs'].apply(func)
print (df)
    IDs
0  text
1     1
2     1
```